# Why might cd call the function ':'?

Tags: linux, bash, function, amazon-ec2, cd

I am using Ubuntu (Amazon EC2), and when I type `cd`, this happens:

```
$ cd
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
$
```

I had previously made : be a function: `: () { echo hi; }`

This happens in the top-level shell `$SHLVL=1`, but not in any subshell (typing `bash` then trying to reproduce this does not work).

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: "I had previously made : be a function" ... Dare I ask why?

Comment: @ceejayoz Probably because the LDP [mentions that you can!](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) ;)

Comment: Is `cd` a function? Is `PROMPT_COMMAND` set? Please run the above again with `set -x` and provide the output.

Comment: Can someone duplicate this behavior?  Making the `:` function does not cause `cd` to exhibit the above behavior here, with Ubuntu 15.10's bash version 4.3.42(1)-release.  I tried it in a tty console login shell, and in an xterm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did is a very poor idea because `:` is the shell null command.

It is useful from time to time in constructs that require a command. For instance, if you want code an infinite loop using `while`, it helps:

```
while true ; do
  :
done
```

Take out the `:` and it's not well-formed any more: `do` requires a command. Out of the following three one-liners, only the last one is correct—try them:

```
while true do done
while true do ; done
while true do : ; done
```

If you redefine `:` as a function, a good question is: is that well defined? But never mind that, suppose it works. Suddenly, these occurrences of `:` that crop up in scripts from time to time will be calling your function!

What is `cd` in the Amazon EC2 shell environment? Maybe it's a function. Type `set` and browse through the output.  I've often defined a custom `cd` function; it's useful to do. You can do things like dynamically update the prompt and window title and whatnot.

Comment: `cd` is indeed defined as a function as shown by `set`. I cannot see exactly how `:` may be called, but I have not checked the entire output. Thank you for your answer.